# Why is create react app not importing a css file?

Tags: javascript, css

[enter image description here][1]Problem: no CSS in output.

Methods tried to fix:

1. renaming `styles.css` to `styles.module.css` -- fail
2. manual load Webpack in terminal even though it shouldn't need it with `create-react-app` -- fail
3. Tried the syntax - import styles from `./styles.module.css`; - and also just `import ./styles.module.css`; and `import styles.module.css`; -- fail

So I've been googling for hours and nothing has seemed to do the trick.  A link is provided with what the code.  when it runs, the terminal clearly says line 4 is defined but never used as is evident by the greyed out line in visual studio code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4PdW.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdKYB.png

I appreciate any help.  Thank you in advance

Comment: create-react-app should have CSS working out of the box w/o need to mess with Webpack. Can you paste your file directory, and code where you're importing css

Comment: won't let me post a pic directly but I added the link that was supposed to be at the bottom of the post and wasn't.  My apologies, I thought it was already attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i have seen you did was `import styles from "./styles.module.css"` but not used **styles**

As well as `import "./styles.module.css"` not sure this will work as well because your styles will be scoped. (This i did not test it is just assumption)

This is from create react app docs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // reference as a js object
    return <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>;
  }
}
```

If you add **module** in file name of styles.

Use `import styles from './Button.module.css';` and then use **styles** to access content in file something like `styles.[class-name-from-Button.module.css]`

If you just have `Button.css` just call `import './Button.css';` somewhere on top, do not add module in between Button and css

Comment: ok so styles.[class-name-from-Button.module.css] worked to apply the setting to that specific classname, which is great.  Thanks a TON!  Is there not a way to apply the CSS across the file though with just the classname?  So every time I have to write - className={styles.className} instead of className='className' ? I ask because I have -- html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
} in css that needs to be applied across the entire file and I'm not sure I know how to do that.

Comment: That would be something like global styles. So you can have file in your **src/global.css** folder, but do not add **module** name, and just use `import ./global.css` in your **src/index.css**. The styles from global.css would be applied everywhere.